# HTML instead of json object in fetch request

Tags: next.js, fetch, prisma

Hello everyone I'm just kind of in front of a wall. I hope you can help me. I want to query the data from the database with Prisma. I do this in the api folder and then call it with a fetch request. In the browser the api returns a correct json object but in the code the fetch request returns an html.

Fetch Request:

```
export default async function ListCompanies() {
  const companies: any = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/company/fetch"
  ).then((res) => res.json());
  console.log("companies", companies);
  return (
```

API:

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "../../auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { prisma } from "@/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function GET() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (!session) {
    redirect("/api/auth/signin");
  }

  const currentUserEmail = session?.user?.email!;
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: currentUserEmail,
    },
  });
  if (user) {
    const companies = await prisma.company.findMany({
      where: {
        user: user?.id,
      },
    });
    return NextResponse.json(companies);
  }
  return;
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: "the fetch request returns an html" — As what HTML? Is the API returning an HTML representation of the data instead of a JSON representation of it? Is the API returning an error message expressed as an HTML document?

Comment: "the code the fetch request returns an html" — And you can tell this because you get an error message about being able to parse the JSON since there is a `<` at line 1 character 1?

Answer (score -1):

it is cause of this lines of code:

```
  const companies: any = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/company/fetch"
  ).then((res) => res.json());
```

change it to something like this:

```
// outside of your component
async function getCompanies() {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/company/fetch`)
  return res.json()
}


// inside your component
const artistData = getCompanies()
```

but there exsists many more ways to fix it, please let me know if it works

Comment: Your changes appear to use alternative syntax to achieve *exactly the same* result.